# Accessing Internal page with external IP and port

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a VM running Orion that has an internal status page. Example https://<cluster.com>/internal
I have assigned an external IP to the host and I'm about to SFTP and SSH to the host perfectly. But this internal page requires port 2201 to be open. Which I do have open. But I can't access the site with https://external-IP/internal. If I create a VPN to the network on GCP from my laptop I am able to connect using the https://internal-IP/internal. I'm not a network expert or a GCP expert an help would be welcomed.

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you are using Compute Engine or App Engine Flexible Environment with Custom Runtime and little more details on your use case? Regarding connecting to instances without external IP addresses VPN is one of the way that you have mentioned. This document [1] provides some other ways to conenct.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#connecting_to_instances_without_external_ip_addresses

Comment: Compute Engine. I was able to using the following  https://external-IP/internal/internal-IP:2201

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern worked for me in the GCP Compute Engine

```
https://external-IP/internal/internal-IP:2201
```